# No Error while Using JSON.parse(JSON.stringfy()) but error with the Object.assign({}, )

Tags: typescript

Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Map<string, string>'.

`const tim: Map<string, string> = Object.assign({}, d.getCustomProperties()[propertyName])[props.id];`

Comment: Without a bit more of context and code it's gonna be very difficult to answer this question. The data you're working with could have any kind of shape.

Answer (score 0):

`JSON.parse` has a return type of `any` which in turn means that it does satisfy the `Map` constraint. The `Object.assign` statement however returns a `{}` type that does not satisfy the `Map` constraint.

Keep in mind that an object does not comply with the `Map` type, the map type has to support `set` and `get`, these methods are not supported for every object.

If you want to use a key value setup without having to use `new Map`([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)) you can use the following type:

```
interface MyDictionary {[key: string]: string};

{"test": "myValue"} // Satisfies the MyDictionary constraint.
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that types in Typescript are just compile time checks and not enforced at runtime. Even though the type of d.getCustomProperties() is Record<string, string>. when js sees a json like structure it's automatically converting it to an object which is why JSON.parse was failing. Typescript was expecting a string so I get compile time warnings when I try and treat it like an object.

```
// @ts-ignore
const tim = (d.getCustomProperties()[propertyName] as object)[props.id];
```

It works as it basically tells Typescript to ignore the compile time check and to treat it like an object.